# kotlin compile always assume java method return nullable value, unless method annotate @NonNull

Tags: java, kotlin

How to let kotlin compile always assume java method return nullable value, unless method annotate @NonNull.
Is any kotlin compile param can achieve?

for example, a `getString` method return null:

```java
public class JavaClass {
  public String getString() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

when call from kotlin, it can direct call `getString` without null check:

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val str = JavaClass().string
  str.length
}
```

I want kotlin compile force treat `getString` return a nullable value, then `str` must use after null check like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val str = JavaClass().string
  str?.length
}
```

Comment: It is unlikely there exists such a compiler flag because there’s no way to prevent Java code from returning null. If you had to guard against it, all Java method calls that don’t return primitive types would be littered with null checks.

Comment: Can you edit the Java code? Making an annotation with `@TypeQualifierDefault`, and marking every class with it could work.

Comment: I can not edit java code @sweeper

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. To quote a JetBrains Team member from a similar [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/forcing-platform-type-to-always-nullable/3136/3) on Kotlin Forums:

> platform types are not, and are not going to be, always nullable

The same person also mentioned [this talk](https://youtu.be/2IhT8HACc2E?si=7Vs2aS19oDjVsbgL) by Andrey Breslau, which explained this decision. To summarise, this would introduce a lot of `?.`s and `!!`s when calling Java code. It becomes a lot more inconvenient when you want to assert generic type parameters to be non-null. If a Java method returns `List<String>`, it would become `List<String?>?` if it treated all Java types as nullable. Although you can assert that the list is not null with `!!`, you cannot do the same to assert that `String`s in the list are also non-null, without an unchecked cast.

If you really want to do this, your only option is to edit the Java code - annotate it with nullable annotations. You can make use of [`@TypeQualifierDefaults`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#type-qualifier-defaults) to make this process easier.

If you just want a warning/error to be emitted when you assign a platform type to a non-nullable type, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45690785/5133585). You can write your own IDE plugin that does this.

Comment: Basically, what I said in my comment “_If you had to guard against it, all Java method calls that don’t return primitive types would be littered with null checks_”

Answer (score 0):

Since the Kotlin compiler take [Java nullability annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) (like jsr305  @Nullable) into account, you could annotate your java methods with such annotations to obtain the desired behavior.

```
public class JavaClass {
  @CheckForNull
  public String getString() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This can be done at the package level via package-info.java files.

```
@CheckForNull
package mypackage;
```

Note that it could be better to reverse this logic: use package-info to annotate all methods as returning non-null and specify only the nullable ones as in the first code sample above. This would gain you the same kind of null-safety on the java side a on the kotlin side, assuming you use one of the tools available to enforce these annotations.

(from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-package-info))

```
@NonNullApi
package mypackage;
```

Comment: But if i can not edit java code , how to achieve?

Comment: Then see Sweeper answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77414666/9756362